# Django Search and Submit button in the same form

Tags: python, django, forms, search, get

I need some advice on how to implement this. I am quite new at Django.

My website is a musical community that helps people find instruments that other musicians nearby are willing to lend to them in a time of need.

It's really important according to my UX designer to have a Submit and Search button in the same form. So the user can either Submit a new listing or Search for an existing one in the parameters entered.

The problem for me is according to my Django book, searches should be done with the `GET` method, and Submits should be done with `POST`. Also, where do I write the search functionality in the `views.py` file?

This is what I want:
[image: Search and Submit]

Comment: That's funny coming from a UX designer, I thought [Your Form Buttons Should Never Say ‘Submit’](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-your-form-buttons-should-never-say-submit/)

Comment: ...you're right, in her design it says "Post" :-)

Comment: Not sure, if that makes it any better :) From your question it looks like something that could be done in Javascript rather than Django.

Comment: I must agree, IMO this is pretty terrible UI design. Having a form do two completely different things, with only similar-shaped buttons to distinguish which, is a recipe for user confusion.

Comment: You could add the `formaction` and `formmethod` attributes to your buttons to override the form's. Although it would only work in IE10+ and, as other have stated, confuse the hell out of your users.